# How to configure ModelConfig.txt for TensorRT Models in Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving

Currently, in Tensorflow Serving you can specify a ModelConfig.txt that maps to a ModelConfig.proto file.  This file contains a list of configurations for multiple models that will run within the Tensorflow Serving instance.

For Example:

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name: "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco",
    base_path: "/test_models/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco/",
    model_platform: "tensorflow"
  },
  config: {
    name: "faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco",
    base_path: "/test_models/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco/",
    model_platform: "tensorflow"
  }
}
```

As it stands when I attempt to place a TensorRT optimized model into the ModelConfig.txt the system fails.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you add the error stack trace?